# Why does this take so long to run?

Tags: java, io

I'm a newbie to java, and I'm reading in a ~25 MB file, and it takes forever to just load... Are there any alternatives to make this faster? Is it the Scanner that can't handle large files?

```
String text = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("text.txt"));
while(sc.hasNext()) {
text += sc.next();
}
```

Comment: Try Apache Commons IO http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Comment: Though I am pretty sure the jvm will optimize it for you, try using a [`StrinbgBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of string concat, and create your string object only when you are done reading the file and building your string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are concatenating to text every iteration, and Strings are **immutable** in Java. This means it creates a new `String` object in memory every time `text` is "modified," resulting in long load times for large files. You should *always* try and use a `StringBuilder` when you are continuously altering a `String`.

You could do:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("text.txt");
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  text.append(sc.next());
}
```

When you want to access the contents of text, you can call `text.toString()`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense... I changed String to StringBuilder and it worked wonders! It went from 2 minute load times to 20 seconds!! Thanks Song!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. @assylias I agree, BufferedString was obsolete since 1.5. Edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

It is the `String +=`, which creates everytime an evergrowing new String object.
In fact for smaller than 25 MB one could do (undermore):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(new File("text.txt"), "UTF-8")));
for (;;) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null)
        break;
    sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
in.close();
String text = sb.toString();
```

`readLine` yields the line upto the newline character(s), not including them.

In Java 7 one could do:

```
Path path = Paths.get("text.txt");
String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), "UTF-8");
```

The encoding is given explicitly, as UTF-8. "Windows-1252" would be for Windows Latin-1 etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `BufferedStreams`, e.g, `BufferedInputStream, BufferedReader` they will accelerate it. For more information about `BufferedStreams` take a look at here;
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html

And instead of `String` use `StringBuilder` since `String`s are immutable in `Java`, it will create a new `String` within each iteration of `while` loop